# Can I get the type of copy protection on a CD/DVD in C#?

Tags: c#, copy-protection

I know there are several tools out there that can detect the type of CD/DVD protection.
Is there a library or code sample that will help me get this information in C#?

Answer (score 3):

CD and DVD copyright protection methods are *very* different. As far as I know, only DVD has any standardized copyright protection mechanism; the [DVD_COPYRIGHT_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553715.aspx) structure and related API might be helpful.

(You may end up needing to send commands directly to the DVD drive, since Windows doesn't support every feature a drive supports. Take a look at [my C# SCSI Library](http://scsi.codeplex.com) if you need to do that, and let me know if you need features that aren't implemented yet. :) )

Comment: The world is small. I am the person who actually had problems running your library and we discussed this on your issue tracker. I was going to use your library but I could not solve exception issues. Where exactly are the copyright commands in your library?

Comment: @Mert: Oh haha wow, okay. About the exception issues: You mentioned that you're getting the exceptions on *virtual* drives... okay, but given that you said it works on real drives, I think it's obviously a problem with your virtual driver. I have no idea how the binary version could possibly work when the source doesn't... they're the same. Feel free to discuss this more on the tracker. And about the copyright commands: That's why I said if you need features that aren't implemented, let me know. ;) Are you talking about AACS, CSS, or something else? What do you specifically need implemented?